# Smooth a modeled objected

Tags: modeling

I just finished modeling this small pillar which **I would like to have the curved parts smooth in the final rende**r.

[image]

This is the model in Xray.
[image]

I have tried the following modifiers to smooth it out.
Bevel
Subdivision or Multiresolution
Smooth.

but obtained this result.

[image]

The Best I could obtain is the following with an object / shade smooth.
[image]

**The result is good but I would like to know why am I not managing it out with the subdivision and Bavel modifiers when many of the tutorials I see use them?**

I have uploaded the file for anyone who wants to try it out.

[image]

Thanks in advance for and advise and help.

Comment: Hello :). There are many n-gons, which prevent the Bevel Modifier and smooth shading from working. I'd strongly advise to make the mesh all quads. It won't take long, the model is very simple.

Comment: Pardon my newness, so quads are 4 edged polygons but how much do n-gons have?

Comment: Hello again :). N-gons are any polygons with *more than 4* edges. They're easy to create, but usually bring more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically in most cases you need just to [Auto Smooth Normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html) at mesh data properties:

[image: [Auto Smooth Normals]

Use [Shade Smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/smooth.html?highlight=shade%20smooth) for object globally (or selectively in Edit mode):

[image: Shade Smooth]

Sometimes when you import object from exchange formats may be needed to [Clear Custom Split Normals Data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/custom_data.html?highlight=clear%20custom%20split%20normals%20data):

[image: Clear Custom Split Normals Data]

Another solution to achieve Auto Smooth Normals data effect is applying of [Edge Split Modified](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html) especially at work with curves or linked data.